# Issue using the Cases function when forming a function of parameters

Tags: list-manipulation

This is my code so far:

```
k = Import["all.txt.", "Table"]

Cases[k, {name_, G_, H_, S_, Cp_, V_, a1a_, a2b_, a3c_,a4d_, c1e_, c2f_, omegalan_, cT_}
      /; name == "compoundname" -> {Cp, G, S}]
```

(The contents of `all.txt` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/HfCP7nFh).)

This imports a table of 2000 different compounds, each having 12 different numerical values. Right now when I alter `"compoundname"` to for instance `"water"` the values I desire (here `Cp`, `G` and `S`) will appear for water.

I am trying to alter this to make it so I can type the desired name into a simple function instead by attempting something like this:

```
HKFparameters[compoundname_] :=
   Cases[k, {name_, G_, H_, S_, Cp_, V_, a1a_, a2b_, a3c_, a4d_, c1e_, c2f_, omegalan_, cT_} /;
         name == "compoundname" -> {Cp, G, S}]
```

I have tried modifying this line in multiple ways but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Can you post `all.txt` somewhere, so other people can help you?

Comment: You might want to put the contents in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: okay i did that and here is the link: http://pastebin.com/HfCP7nFh

Comment: Some of your table rows convert to 15 elements, others to 14, so you have import problems. But your function is looking for exactly 13 patterns, and so doesn't match - have a look at "__" in the documentation, which matches one or more elements. Also, you shouldn't have the quotes around 'compoundname', because that's going to be the function parameter...

Comment: the importing of the file works fine for me but okay i will remove the quotes thanks

Comment: Eg 'rh20', 'sulfur' (first occurrence), and the compounds and acids are blanks, or have spaces between words, and so the `Import` function creates lists with varying numbers of 13-15 elements. So this makes it harder to use the data in Mathematica. (Check with `Union[Dimensions[#] & /@ k]`.) While this could be fixed in Mathematica, perhaps it would be better for you to fix the data first.

Comment: thank you very much, i edited the paste and i believe i fixed the issues http://pastebin.com/HfCP7nFh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think your (revised) data is still not completely consistent, it's probably good enough for now.

```
k = Import["t.txt", "Table"];
```

Some rows are different lengths:

```
Union[Dimensions[#]  & /@ k]
```

> {{13}, {14}, {15}}

We can find them easily:

```
Cases[{#, Dimensions[#]} & /@  k , {line_, {13 | 15}}] // Sort

{{{"1-methylnaphthalene", 46772, 11259, 52.15, 46.45, -9.75, 183.2, 1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000}, {13}},
 {{"Rh2O", -19100, -22700, 27.4, 0, 15.59, 6.47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1273}, {13}},
 {{"sulfur1", 0, 0, 7.6, 15.511, 3.58, 6.24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368.6}, {13}},
 {{"acetic", "acid", -92284, -115349, 36.88, 29.42, 49.8, 12.04, 58.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 391.05}, {15}}, 
 {{"acide", "fulvique", -2901050, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 0, "NA"}, {15}}, 
 {{"acide", "humique", -1775100, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 0, "NA"}, {15}}, 
...
```

You can see why this is a problem: some of the fields have been shifted to the right because of the way the `Import` command split the names with spaces.

But at least we can work with the 14-column rows:

```
HKFparameters[compoundname_] := 
 Cases[k, {name_, G_, H_, S_, Cp_, V_, a1a_, a2b_, a3c_, c1e_, c2f_, 
    omegalan_, cT_, _} /; name == compoundname];

HKFparameters["2,3-dimethyl-2-butanethiol"]

{{"2,3-dimethyl-2-butanethiol", 5881, -34716, 98.36, 39.56, 0, 2.28, 142.2, 0, 0, -5.758, 0, 0, 1000}, 
 {"2,3-dimethyl-2-butanethiol", 3602, -44345, 73.71, 52.19, 140.8, 20.78, 96.2, 2.428, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000}}

HKFparameters["CeCO3+"]

{{"CeCO3+", -297887, -332620, -40.6, -65.4, -22.8, -0.916, -10.0134, 9.6736, -2.3649, -21.4145, -16.3769, 1.1729, 1}}
```

#### Update

As michael observes, if the input file is correctly tabbed, you can import using `k = Import["k.txt", "TSV"]`. In your case this gives a 'table' with half a dozen or so blank spaces in each 'line' (positions 2 to 7), which you can remove easily enough:

```
k1 = Drop[#, { 2, 7}] & /@ k

k1 // Dimensions
```

> {3020, 14}

Another thing worth pointing out is that, if the original had been an Excel file, it would be worth trying to import it directly (`Import["file.xls"]`)...

Comment: thank you so much i really appreciate the help! i will continue to edit the data and then it will work perfect.

Comment: @KateMcCallum `Import["all.txt", "TSV"]` results in a regular array (3020 rows x 20 columns), for the pastebin file.